# How to use service account in Python on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I'm wondering how to use Service Account on Google App Engine standard environment.
I wrote some codes like below to access BigQuery with a proper JSON key file.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
....
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(proper_path_to_json_key)
list(bigquery_client.list_datasets())
```

The code works OK when I run it on a local Python interpreter but results miserably failed with the following error when it runs on local `dev_appserver.py`.

```
TransportError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

When it runs on GAE, it still fails but its error message is like below.

```
TransportError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(208 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(208 bytes read))
```

I think this error is caused by GAE's restriction on outbound traffic described here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests
but I have no idea how to resolve it.

What is the best way to use Service Account on GAE environment?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, App Engine Standard does not yet support Google Client Libraries such as the BigQuery library you are attempting to use, as stated [in this GitHub topic](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1893#issuecomment-322512490), although it is work in progress.

Alternatively, you can rather try a deployment in App Engine Flexible if that fits your requirements, or try the [Google API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_api_client_libraries) instead.

Regarding your question about using Service Accounts with App Engine, you can either use the default built-in service accounts available when running that service, or create custom ones. You can find more information about the usage of service accounts in App Engine Standard in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#using_service_accounts).